# Too few arguments to function App\User::hasRole() Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Помогите исправить, понять откуда проблема (только начал учить ларавел пхп)
Ошибка ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\User::hasRole()

User model

```
   public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->roles()->where("role_id", $role)->admin_id) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

web

```
Route::get('/admin', function (){
    if (Gate::allows('admin_section', Auth::user())){
    return view('admin.index');
    } else {
    return redirect('/login');
    }}); Auth::routes();
```

role.php

```
class Role extends Model{
const admin_id = 1;
const user_id = 2;
const teacher_id = 3;
const student_id = 4;

public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','users_roles','role_id','user_id');
}
```

AuthService

```
public function boot(){
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Gate::define('admin_section', function ($user) {
        return $user->hasRole();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция hasRole ждет аргумент ($role):

```
public function hasRole($role)
```

Вы не передаете ей при вызове вообще ничего:

```
return $user->hasRole();
```

Или передавайте значение или установите значение по умолчанию в объявлении функции

Answer (score -1):

Fix your user model:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
   if ($this->roles()->where("role_id", $role)->first()->admin_id) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```